# Multi-lingual action button for Gmail Schemas?

Tags: google-schemas

I am just wondering if Google is going to support multi-lingual action buttons. Say for an RSVP email, if the user's browser is in Japanese, the action button would display RSVP in Japanese.

Also if this is going to happen, would it also support customized one-click buttons?

Answer (score 1):

All action button labels will soon be automatically localized if you are not specifying a custom label for your action. If you want to use a custom label and add the `action.name` property to your markup, then you have to take care of the localization.